# parameter not passed to the function when using walk function in PURRR package

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am using the purrr:walk to read multiple excel files and it failed. I have 3 questions:

(1) I used the function list.files to read the excel file list in one folder. But the returned values also included the subfolders. I tried set value for the parameters recursive= and include.dirs=, but it didn't work.

```
setwd(file_path)

files<-as_tibble(list.files(file_path,recursive=F,include.dirs=F)) %>%
  filter(str_detect(value,".xlsx"))
files
```

(2) When I used the following piece of code, it can run without any error or warning message, but there is no returned data.

```
###read the excel data
file_read <- function(value1) {
  print(value1)
  file1<-read_excel(value1,sheet=1)
}

walk(files$value,file_read)
```

When I used the following, it worked. Not sure why.

```
test<-read_excel(files$value,sheet=1)
```

(3) In Q2, actually I want to create file1 to file6, suppose there are 6 excel files. How can I dynamically assign the dataset name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.files` has `pattern` argument where you can specify what kind of files you are looking for. This will help you avoid `filter(str_detect(value,".xlsx"))` step. Also `list.files` only returns the files that are included in the main directory (`file_path`) and not it's subdirectory unless you specify `recursive = TRUE`.

```
library(readxl)
setwd(file_path)

files <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xlsx')
```

In the function you need to `return` the object.

```
file_read <- function(value1) {
  data <- read_excel(value1,sheet=1)
  return(data)
}
```

Now you can use `map`/`lapply` to read the files.

```
result <- purrr::map(files,file_read)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I just have a further question. The object "result" is a list, in which each element contains a tibble. How can I convert the object result to a tibble? I can use result2=rbind(result[[1]],result[[2]]), but the number of element may not be fixed.

Comment: You can use `map_df` to combine them into one dataframe i.e `result <- purrr::map_df(files,file_read)`